# Does the User model need :password and :password_confirmation to be set as attr_accesible in authlogic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic

I've been trying to setup Authlogic for the first time but I'm confused.

I have set it up as per the example in the [authlogic_example](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic_example) code however it doesn't appear to run:

```
u = User.new(:password=>'testpass',
             :password_confirmation => 'testpass', 
             :email => 'test@test.com')
=> #<User id: nil, email: "test@test.com", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, 
          first_name: nil, last_name: nil, crypted_password: nil, 
          password_salt: nil, persistence_token: nil>
 >> u.valid?
 => false
 >> u.errors
 => #< OrderedHash {:password=>["is too short (minimum is 4 characters)"], 
                    :password_confirmation=>["is too short 
                                            (minimum is 4 characters)"]}>
```

It looked like :password and :password_confirmation simply weren't being set so in class User I made :password and :password_confirmation accessible attributes:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_authentic
  attr_accessible :password, :password_confirmation # changed code
end
```

That worked:

```
>> u = User.new(:password=>'testpass',:password_confirmation => 'testpass', 
                :email => 'test@test.com')
=> #<User id: nil, email: "test@test.com", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, 
          first_name: nil, last_name: nil, 
          crypted_password: "446edcbee34254ea83b8d469baef2dc34d723e710faf22efb97...", 
          password_salt: "hZFVKUo66meyrZ97Gb", 
          persistence_token: "b469fefd82a91683bf51b5eb9dbc15563b569a93ce973a42595...">
>> u.valid?
=> true
```

Whilst this worked, I'm concerned that I've been doing something wrong because in the authlogic_example, there are no attr_accessible set in user:

```
# Authlogic_example code
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_authentic
end
```

Why is it that the authlogic_example code works without explicitly setting the attributes to be being accessible but mine doesn't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suddenly realised what caused my problem.

I had previously changed the default setting for mass_assignment in a config file to enforce that all attributes were protected unless declared otherwise.

An obvious mistake in retrospect but hopefully this might save someone else some time too

Answer (score 1):

Attr_accessible is a safety feature. It tells your model to only save the mentioned values, upon a mass assignment (like save). Im' pretty sure that you will notice a Warning on mass assignment if you look at your logs.

If you have try to save a model even with a single accessible attribute, ONLY this will be saved in a mass assignment. Thus, if you have :password accessible but :password_confirmation not accessible, only :password will be inserted, and you will get a warning.

I think that this is probably the reason why you get this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Peter Nixey's answer, to resolve this problem in rails 3 I changed the following:

```
# application.rb
config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = false #it was true
```

When set to true, a whitelist is enforced for all attributes that can be mass assigned. This needs to be disabled or you can add them to the white list with

```
attr_accessible <your attributes>
```

**Edit**

As Peter quite rightly points out in the comments; by setting the configuration to false you leave yourself open to mass_assignment attacks, so using the white list is the securest option,

Comment: That was definitely what was causing the problem but it's a good idea to set whitelist_attributes to true or you leave yourself open to mass_assignment attacks